# Monitor activity on a network

Tags: c++, websocket

I wrote a small C++ program to monitor activity (messages sent) on a network and display the current status of the machines. The assumptions are as follows:

There exist sessions on a network. A session is made up of one master machine and several slave machines sending messages. On a startup masters and slaves both broadcast a message and then send a regular heartbeat messages. These two message types use a similar protocol but are sent on different ports. Machines can start up and shut down in any order. An active machine can crash and then recover by sending a startup message again. There may be multiple sessions (multiple master and slave networks) active on a network at any one time.

---

Protocol 1 -
each message is contained within a single data packet and these are broadcast over UDP port 7106. The message is sent as a plaintext string.

Master sends this on startup:
**SESSION|sessionname|creator|machineid1|machineid2|machineid3|machinen**

Example:
**SESSION|my session|adamspc|lukespc|mattspc**

Slaves sends this on startup:
**PC|machineid|sessionname**

Example:
**PC|alexspc|my session**

There are other message types sent over the protocol that should be ignored.

---

Protocol 2 -
each message is contained within a single data packet and these are broadcast over UDP port 7104. The message is sent as a plaintext string.

Every machine sends this at least once a second
**PCSTATUS|machineid|version|fps**

Example:
**PCSTATUS|johnspc|11.2|60**

There are other message types sent over the protocol that should be ignored.

state diagram for each machine is as follows:

[image]

I would appreciate any feedback, what should be improved, added etc. Could be just regarding some parts (socket handling, messages processing, way of capturing data etc).

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#define PORT      7104
#define PORT2     7106
#define MAXLINE   1024

using namespace std;

int max(int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) return x; else return y;
}

struct machInfo {
    string name;
    string lastHeartBeatTs;

    machInfo(const string& name) : name(name) {}
};

struct sessInfo {
    string name;
    string master;
    vector<string> slaves;

    sessInfo(const string& name) : name(name) {}
};

struct netInfo {
    map<string, sessInfo> sessions;
    map<string, machInfo> machines;

    void procDataSock1(string& data);
    void procDataSock2(string& data);

    void printInfo() {
        // TODO print info about the network
    }
};

// if it's a heartbeat msg then capture the timestamp
void netInfo::procDataSock1(string& data) {
    string delimiter = "|", msgType, machine;

    size_t pos = 0;
    pos = data.find(delimiter);
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        msgType = data.substr(0, pos);
        data.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    else
        return;

    if (msgType == "PCSTATUS") {
        pos = data.find(delimiter);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            machine = data.substr(0, pos);
        }
        else
            return;

        map<string, machInfo>::iterator it = machines.find(machine);
        if ( it != machines.end() ) {
            time_t _tm = time(NULL);
            struct tm * curtime = localtime ( &_tm );
            string ts(asctime(curtime));

            it->second.lastHeartBeatTs = ts;
        }
    }
}

// if it's a SESSION or MESSAGE msg, then capture the available info and store it
void netInfo::procDataSock2(string& data) {
    string delimiter = "|", msgType, session, machine, master;

    size_t pos = 0;
    pos = data.find(delimiter);
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        msgType = data.substr(0, pos);
        data.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    else
        return;

    if (msgType == "SESSION") {
        pos = data.find(delimiter);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            session = data.substr(0, pos);
            data.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        else
            return;

        pos = data.find(delimiter);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            master = data.substr(0, pos);
            data.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        else
            return;

        map<string, sessInfo>::iterator it1 = sessions.find(session);
        if ( it1 == sessions.end() ) {
            sessions.insert(pair<string, sessInfo>(session,
                                                   sessInfo(session)));
        }
        else
            it1->second.master = master;

        map<string, machInfo>::iterator it2 = machines.find(master);
        if ( it2 == machines.end() ) {
            machines.insert(pair<string, machInfo>(master,
                                                   machInfo(master)));
        }
    }
    else if (msgType == "PC") {
        pos = data.find(delimiter);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            machine = data.substr(0, pos);
            data.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        else
            return;

        session = data;

        map<string, sessInfo>::iterator it1 = sessions.find(session);
        if ( it1 == sessions.end() ) {
            sessions.insert(pair<string, sessInfo>(session,
                                                   sessInfo(session)));
        }

        map<string, machInfo>::iterator it2 = machines.find(machine);
        // if first startup message we need to add it to machines
        if ( it2 == machines.end() ) {
            machines.insert(pair<string, machInfo>(machine,
                                                   machInfo(machine)));
            it1 = sessions.find(session);
            // will always evaluate to true
            if ( it1 != sessions.end() ) {
                it1->second.slaves.push_back(machine);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    netInfo ni;

    int sockfd, sockfd2;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, servaddr2;

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( (sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr,  0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&servaddr2, 0, sizeof(servaddr2));

    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(PORT);

    servaddr2.sin_family      = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr2.sin_port        = htons(PORT2);

    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( bind(sockfd2, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr2,
            sizeof(servaddr2)) < 0 ) 
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int cnt = 1;
    while (true) {

        // print info about the system every 20 messages
        if (cnt++ % 20 == 0)
            ni.printInfo();

        fd_set socks;
        FD_ZERO(&socks);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &socks);
        FD_SET(sockfd2, &socks);

        int nsocks = max(sockfd, sockfd2) + 1;

        if (select(nsocks, &socks, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, 0) >= 0) {

            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &socks)) {
                // handle socket 1
                char buffer[MAXLINE];

                struct sockaddr_storage src_addr;
                socklen_t src_addr_len=sizeof(src_addr);
                int n = recvfrom( sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),
                            0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr,&src_addr_len);
                if (n==-1) {
                    cout << "error... " << endl;
                } else if (n==sizeof(buffer)) {
                    cout << "datagram too large for buffer" << endl;
                } else {

                    buffer[n] = '\0';
                    string data(buffer);
                    ni.procDataSock1(data);
                }
            }

            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd2, &socks)) {
                // handle socket 2
                char buffer[MAXLINE];

                struct sockaddr_storage src_addr;
                socklen_t src_addr_len=sizeof(src_addr);
                int n = recvfrom( sockfd2, buffer, sizeof(buffer),
                            0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr,&src_addr_len);

                if (n==-1) {
                    cout << "error... " << endl;
                } else if (n==sizeof(buffer)) {
                    cout << "datagram too large for buffer" << endl;
                } else {

                    buffer[n] = '\0';
                    string data(buffer);
                    ni.procDataSock2(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your message protocol obligatory or optional ? Maybe json and strongly typed messaging would be safer.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Standard advice is to avoid depriving yourself of the benefits of the `std` namespace like this.  Prefer to import *just the names you need*, into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  Or just qualify names as you use them; `std` is intentionally a very short name.

---

> ```
> int max(int x, int y) {
>     if (x > y) return x; else return y;
> }
> ```

This seems unnecessary, given that we can simply use `std::max()` (and might even start doing so unintentionally, given the `using` declaration above).

---

> ```
> machInfo(const string& name) : name(name) {}
> ```

If we pass by value, we can avoid copying when given an rvalue `name`:

```
machInfo(std::string name)
  : name{std::move(name)}
{}
```

---

> ```
> void procDataSock1(string& data);
> void procDataSock2(string& data);
> ```

Naming is hard - but surely we can do better than this??

---

> ```
>     if (pos != string::npos) {
>         machine = data.substr(0, pos);
>     }
>     else
>         return;
> ```

It's easier to read if we turn this around, to deal with the problem case first:

```
    if (pos == string::npos) {
        return;
    }

    machine = data.substr(0, pos);
```

We now no longer need `else`.

---

> ```
>     map<string, machInfo>::iterator it = machines.find(machine);
> ```

`auto` is useful for types like this:

```
    auto const it = machines.find(machine);
```

---

> ```
>     map<string, sessInfo>::iterator it1 = sessions.find(session);
>     if ( it1 == sessions.end() ) {
>         sessions.insert(pair<string, sessInfo>(session,
>                                                sessInfo(session)));
>     }
> ```

That's exactly equivalent to `try_emplace()`:

```
    sessions.try_emplace(session, session);
```

---

> ```
>     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
> ```

`std::exit` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are both declared by `<cstdlib>`, but it hasn't been included.  Given that this is `main()`, consider plain `return` instead of `std::exit()`.

---

> ```
> servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET; // IPv4
> ```

No IPv6 support?

---

> ```
>     perror("bind failed");
> ```

Good to see use of the proper facilities here.  `std::perror()` is declared in `<cstdio>`, so we need to include that, too.

---

> ```
>                 cout << "datagram too large for buffer" << endl;
> ```

Having seen nice `std::perror()` above, it's a shame that we're using the wrong stream here - error messages should certainly go to `std::cerr`, not `std::cout`.

Comment: Small addition: Use of `std::max` will require `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: Isn't `\n` considered slightly better than `std::endl`?

Comment: @Pedro, I generally agree, but often the implied `flush` can be useful when we're emitting diagnostics like this.  In many cases, that's the last output before the program fails, and we'd hate for this information to be stuck in a buffer.